# Enumerate specific equations with Roman numerals with stars

Tags: equations, subequations

I am drafting a document that has an important system of equations, which I would like to highlight by using Roman numerals to enumerate them. I thought about using the subequations environment, but I do not know how to actually change the enumeration and style for only a specific system of equations. Also, afterwards, I would like to derive a new system from the current one, and I would like to enumerate the new one with Roman numerals with stars (asterisks) to the right of the Roman numerals. I was unable to find the answer via web search. I thank all helpers for any assistance.

Comment: Should the equation numbers increment sequentially all through the document? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico no, I want the numerals to be I, II, III... regardless of the numbering of the other equations in the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've updated the answer to handle the possibility -- not mentioned by the OP, but likely of some relevance to at least some readers -- that the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package is loaded and that correct hyperlinking from cross-references to equations and the corresponding equations is required.)

In the following solution, I assume that the `hyperref` package is loaded. If this assumption is incorrect, you should remove all instances of `\renewcommand\theHequation{...}`.

The solution pursued here creates Roman-numeral and Roman-numeral-plus-star equation "numbers" by (a) resetting the equation counter to `0` (or whatever value is deemed appropriate), (b) redefining the `\theequation` macro as needed, and (c) redefining the `\theHequation` macro. The third step isn't needed if your document doesn't load the `hyperref` package. In addition, the solution defines the utility macros `\SaveEqCtr` and `\RestoreEqCtr` to allow toggling back and forth between ordinary and special forms of the equation number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % for gather environment
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage{cleveref} % for \cref macro

% Create a new counter, to enable toggling back and forth 
%   between ordinary and special forms of equation counters
\newcounter{SaveEqnCntr}
\newcommand\SaveEqCtr{\setcounter{SaveEqnCntr}{\value{equation}}}
\newcommand\RestoreEqCtr{\setcounter{equation}{\value{SaveEqnCntr}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
     0+0=0 \label{a} 
\end{equation}
\SaveEqCtr  % Store the current value of 'equation' counter (=1)

\begingroup % Limit the scope of the next few directives to the current TeX group
\setcounter{equation}{0}
%% Display equation counter using Roman numerals:
\renewcommand\theequation{\Roman{equation}} 
%% If you use 'hyperref', choose a unique identifier, e.g., 
%%   the string 'AA', to redefine the '\theHequation' macro
\renewcommand\theHequation{AA\arabic{equation}} 
\begin{gather} 
     1+1=2 \label{b}  \\ 
     1+2=3 \label{c}  \\
     2+1=3 \label{d}
\end{gather}
\endgroup

\RestoreEqCtr % restore 'standard' form of equation counter
\begin{equation} 
     2+2=4 \label{e} 
\end{equation}
\SaveEqCtr    % Store the current value of 'equation' counter (=2)

\begingroup % Limit the scope of the next few directives to the current TeX group
\setcounter{equation}{0}
%% Display equation counter using Roman numerals plus a 'star'
\renewcommand\theequation{\Roman{equation}$^{\star}$}
%% If you use 'hyperref', choose a unique identifier, e.g., 
%%   the string 'BB', to redefine the '\theHequation' macro
\renewcommand\theHequation{BB\arabic{equation}}
\begin{gather} 
     3+3=6 \label{f} \\ 
     3+4=7 \label{g} \\
     4+3=7 \label{h}
\end{gather}
\endgroup

\RestoreEqCtr % restore 'standard' form of equation counter
\begin{equation} 
     4+4=8 \label{i} 
\end{equation}

\noindent
Cross-references to \cref{b,c,d}, \cref{f,g,h}, and \cref{a,,e,,i}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @kroner - You're most welcome. Please note that I've augmented my answer to allow for the possibility that the document employs the `hyperref` package and hence that the hyperlinks between the cross-referencing call-outs and the associated equations have to "work" as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `\tag`. After all, you just have one special group of equations and you'll need a label for each one of them.

Using (modified) [Mico's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648975/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for gather environment
\usepackage{cleveref} % for \cref macro

\newcounter{maineq}
\renewcommand{\themaineq}{\Roman{maineq}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\maineq}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% call is \maineq*
    \tag{\ref{#2}*}\label{#2*}%
  }{% no *
    \stepcounter{maineq}%
    \tag{\themaineq}\label{#2}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

Cross-references to \cref{good,bad,ugly} and to
\cref{good*,bad*,ugly*}

\begin{equation} 0+0=0 \label{a} \end{equation}

\begin{gather} 
  1+1=2 \maineq{good} \\ 
  1+2=3 \maineq{bad} \\
  2+1=3 \maineq{ugly}
\end{gather}

\begin{equation} 2+2=4 \label{e} \end{equation}

\begin{gather} 
  3+3=6 \maineq*{good} \\ 
  3+4=7 \maineq*{bad} \\
  4+3=7 \maineq*{ugly}
\end{gather}

\begin{equation} 4+4=8 \label{i} \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `cleveref` is not mandatory and cross references with `\ref` will works as well. Anyway, if you use `hyperref`, you may want to change `\ref` in the definition of `\maineq` into `\ref*`, precisely

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\maineq}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% call is \maineq*
    \tag{\ref*{#2}*}\label{#2*}%
  }{% no *
    \stepcounter{maineq}%
    \tag{\themaineq}\label{#2}%
  }%
}
```

If you don't, the tags in the starred equations will be hyperlinks that point to the original equations.

As a bonus, if you use again `\maineq*{good*}`, you will get two asterisks.